# CssRewriteUrlTransform with or without virtual directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification, web-optimization

We are using MVC Bundling in our site, `CssRewriteUrlTransform` makes sure that the image urls work from the dynamic bundle css file.

But this only works when not using a virtual directory, i.e

`http://localhost/VirttualDir` does not work but `http://localhost/` does. This is because the `CssRewriteUrlTransform` tranform does not take the virtual folder into account when rewriting the url. So if a image real path is `localhost/vdir/content/img/foo.png` it will rewrite it to `localhost/content/img/foo.png` which is wrong

Answer (score 107, accepted):

I am not sure to fully understand your problem, but seeing `http://localhost` here seems wrong. You should never use an absolute URL for your bundles.

For me CssRewriteUrlTransform works perfectly, here is how I use it:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css").Include(
                "~/Content/css/*.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()));
```

"Bundles" is virtual.

Does this helps?

### Update

I was confused with the "VirtualDir" thing, as you are talking about IIS VirtualDir, and I was thinking Bundle VirtualDir! It's true that in this case CssRewriteUrlTransform will rewrite URLs to the Host, not to the Host/VirtualDir URI.

To do that, you have to derive CssRewriteUrlTransform to make it do what you need it to.
There is a good discussion here: [ASP.NET MVC4 Bundling with Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577108/asp-net-mvc4-bundling-with-twitter-bootstrap?rq=1)

Seems the best answer is there:http://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/workitem/83

```
public class CssRewriteUrlTransformWrapper : IItemTransform
{
    public string Process(string includedVirtualPath, string input)
    {           
        return new CssRewriteUrlTransform().Process("~" + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(includedVirtualPath), input);           
    }
}
```

Use this class instead of CssRewriteUrlTransform

Comment: The problem appears when your application isn't hosted at the server root, but in a virtual directory. Like `/path/to/my/appRoot/`.

Comment: This put me on the right track but did not work for url( ) that contained a AbsoluteUri already, i needed to detect that so i added a Uri.TryCreate inside a custom version of CssRewriteUrlTranform instead of using a wrapper.

Comment: @jonmeyer Do you have sample code how it is achieved without the transform.

Comment: Working Fine. Thanks :)

Comment: The problem may also appear when your application is behind a portal where some forwarding and so on is done (don't know exact offical wording for our setup).

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. This is how I fixed it:

```
private class ProperUrlRewrite : IItemTransform
{
    private static string RebaseUrlToAbsolute(string baseUrl, string url)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(baseUrl) || url.StartsWith("/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || url.Contains(':'))
            return url;
        return VirtualPathUtility.Combine(baseUrl, url);
    }
    private static Regex UrlPattern = new Regex("url\\s*\\(['\"]?(?<url>[^)]+?)['\"]?\\)");
    public string Process(string includedVirtualPath, string input)
    {
        if (includedVirtualPath == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("includedVirtualPath");
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
            return input;

        string directory = VirtualPathUtility.GetDirectory(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(includedVirtualPath));
        if (!directory.EndsWith("/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            directory += "/";
        return UrlPattern.Replace(input, match => "url(" + ProperUrlRewrite.RebaseUrlToAbsolute(directory, match.Groups["url"].Value) + ")");
    }
}
```

I know it's far from perfect and there are plenty of edge cases where this can go wrong (I'm not sure you can parse a CSS file with a regex in the first place - though this is exactly what the original `CssRewriteUrlTransform` does), but so far it holds...

Answer (score 5):

The 'CssRewriteUrlTransform' works just fine for applications that DOESN'T run on top of a virtual directory.

So, if your app runs on http://your-site.com/ it runs just fine, but if runs on http://your-site.com/your-app/ you'll have 404 for all your images, because the default 'CssFixRewriteUrlTransform' is referencing your images with a '/'.

Use this:

```
public class CssFixRewriteUrlTransform: IItemTransform {

    private static string ConvertUrlsToAbsolute(string baseUrl, string content) {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content)) {
            return content;
        }
        var regex = new Regex("url\\(['\"]?(?<url>[^)]+?)['\"]?\\)");
        return regex.Replace(content, match = > string.Concat("url(", RebaseUrlToAbsolute(baseUrl, match.Groups["url"].Value), ")"));
    }

    public string Process(string includedVirtualPath, string input) {
        if (includedVirtualPath == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("includedVirtualPath");
        }
        var directory = VirtualPathUtility.GetDirectory(includedVirtualPath);
        return ConvertUrlsToAbsolute(directory, input);
    }

    private static string RebaseUrlToAbsolute(string baseUrl, string url) {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(baseUrl) || url.StartsWith("/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
            return url;
        }
        if (!baseUrl.EndsWith("/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
            baseUrl = string.Concat(baseUrl, "/");
        }
        return VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(string.Concat(baseUrl, url));
    }
}
```

Note: delete all file css with .min.css, because if don't it doesn't fix.

Comment: The idea of removing the ".min.css" file helped me out. I guess if the file exists then that file is included directly as an optimization and then the rewriting never takes place.

Comment: You need to take into account data uri formats. Ignore urls starting with "data:" in your RebaseUrlToAbsolute function

Answer (score 0):

I have problems with url that contains "data" and even a url inner another one, so I have to re-do the regex, this is my solution:

```
public string Process(string includedVirtualPath, string input)
    {
        if (includedVirtualPath == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(includedVirtualPath));
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
        {
            return input;
        }

        var directory = VirtualPathUtility.GetDirectory(includedVirtualPath);
        if (!directory.EndsWith("/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            directory += "/";
        }

        return new Regex(@"url\s*\(\s*([\'""]?)(?<scheme>(?:(?:data:)|(?:https?:))?)(?<url>(\\\1|.)*?)\1\s*\)")
            .Replace(input, match => string.Concat(
                "url(",
                match.Groups[1].Value,
                match.Groups["scheme"].Value,
                match.Groups["scheme"].Value == "" ?
                    RebaseUrlToAbsolute(directory, match.Groups["url"].Value) :
                    match.Groups["url"].Value,
                match.Groups[1].Value,
                ")"
            ));
    }

    private static string RebaseUrlToAbsolute(string baseUrl, string url)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(baseUrl)
            || url.StartsWith("/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return url;
        }

        return VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(string.Concat(baseUrl, url));
    }
}
```

based on [RegEx: Grabbing values between quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks/34198968#34198968)