# MVC routing and deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have been struggling with this for a lot of days now. I am a novice to MVC and I m stuck with these issues. I have a mvc application. Following is my route.config file which I understand from a previous post is not proper. My pages are fairly straightforward, there are no query strings, except for one page. every page is controller/view format. What would be the correct routing config for such a configuration. If somebody can help me with that with a little explanation it ll be great. When I deploy that application in IIS, I m having trouble bcoz of this routing.
when I deploy in IIS and I do a browse it directly goes to my login page which is good but internally its going to

```
    http://localhost/Home/accountdetails
```

instead of going to

```
    http://localhost/MyWebsite/Home/accountdetails
```

due to which I m getting a 404 error.I don understand how to set this up. Also my images which are in content folder are not showing up either bcoz they are referring to

```
http://localhost/Content/Images/myimage
```

while they are actually under

```
http://localhost/MySite/Content/Images/myimage
```

how can I correct these issues. Please provide some assistance here.

Here is my route.config

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Home",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "Home",
                    action = "Login",
                    id =
                        UrlParameter.Optional
                }
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Invoice",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{q}",
        defaults: new
        {
            controller = "Home",
            action = "GetInvoice",
            id =
                UrlParameter.Optional
        }
       );

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Error",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new
           {
               controller = "Home",
               action = "Error",
               id =
                   UrlParameter.Optional
           }
       );
        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "ResetPassword",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new
           {
               controller = "Home",
               action = "ResetPassword",
               id
                   = UrlParameter.Optional
           }
       );
        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Accounts",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new
          {
              controller = "Home",
              action = "AccountStatus",
              id
                  = UrlParameter.Optional
          }
      );

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Register",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new
           {
               controller = "Home",
               action = "Register",
               id =
                   UrlParameter.Optional
           }
       );


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "Home",
                action = "Login",
                id =
                    UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        );
    }
}
```

**Update**

For images I am setting the background image  as below

```
<div class="bannerOuter" style="background-image: url('../../Content/Images/AccountStatus_cropped-23.jpg');">
```

but after publishing when I run the application and I press f12 I see that its referring to the below url for the image and throws a 404 error.

```
http://localhost/Content/Images/Accounts_cropped-23.jpg
```

But I can browse to it if I change the url to add my website name that I specified in IIS.

```
http://localhost/MyWebsite/Content/Images/Accounts_cropped-23.jpg
```

So this is the problem what should be my image path in this case.

**Edit**

```
  @Html.EncodedActionLink(string.Format("{0} Statement", @Convert.ToDateTime(@invoiceItem.InvoiceDate).ToString("MMMM")), "GetInvoice", "Home", new { accountNumber = Model.CustomerModel.AccountNumber, dueDate = (Convert.ToDateTime(invoiceItem.DueDate).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")) }, new { target = "_blank", @class = "Link" })
```

So the url here is coming as

```
 http://localhost/Home/GetInvoice?q=ZDmgxmJVjTEfvmkpyl8GGWP4XHfvR%2fyCFJlJM1s0vKj4J6lYJWyEA4QHBMb7kUJq
```

how can I change it to be

```
 http://localhost/MySite/Home/GetInvoice?q=ZDmgxmJVjTEfvmkpyl8GGWP4XHfvR%2fyCFJlJM1s0vKj4J6lYJWyEA4QHBMb7kUJq
```

Comment: All your routes have exactly the same url pattern; the "Home" route is always going to match first and the rest will be completely ignored.  You don't need anything beyond the "Home" route based on your description.  As for the hyperlinks and images, we need to see how you are referring to them in the views.

Comment: Thanks..I did what you suggested and it seemed ok for the views..but for images..please see my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative paths in inline CSS are problematic because it will be relative to the current URL.  So if you go to `http://localhost/MySite/Home/Login` you will need to use `../../Content/myimage.png`.  But, if you go to `http://localhost/MySite`, the default controller and action (`Home/Login`) from route.config will kick in, and now the relative path to the image is `Content/myimage.png` because the controller and action are not explicitly in the URL.  The same problem will happen if you go to `http://localhost/MySite/Home`; the default action (`Login`) will be used and the relative path is `../Content/myimage.png`.

The best solution is to use styles in CSS files and not use inline styles; that way, the image URLs are always relative to the CSS file, whose URL never varies.  Just be aware if you use bundling in `BundleConfig.cs` you need to make sure the path stays consistent [MVC Bundling and CSS relative URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20484188/mvc-bundling-and-css-relative-urls)

But if you need to use inline styles, you can use `@Url.Content()` to always get the correct path, with `~` being the root of your app:

`style="background-image: url('@Url.Content("~/Content/myimage.png")'"`

Comment: Great..thank you so much that worked. Just another question, how can I do that with anchor tags ? I am on the fly generating a pdf file which takes query string parameters which I m encoding. So I have written an htmlhelper extension method as in my edit above. Even with that I have the same problem it takes the relative url and I do not know how to mention the actual url. Hope you can help