# MVC Content Folder urls in css not rendering the same between localhost and production server

Tags: css, .net, model-view-controller, development-environment, production-environment

Im sure this question has been asked somewhere else but I cannot seem to get my google foo to work today.

here is my directory structure

[image: directory structure]

My problem is that in my css, image urls do not render correctly between localhost and the production server

> **example 1**
> works on local host but not production server
>
> ```
> background:url(../Images/mybackground.jpg)
> ```

> **example 2**
> works on server but not localhost
>
> ```
> background:url(../Content/Images/mybackground.jpg)
> ```

Can someone explain why Example1 does not work on the server?

Comment: take a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20484188/mvc-bundling-and-css-relative-urls/20491803 - maybe it can help you

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

The link given by  Mauricio Gracia Gutierrez helped solve this.  Thank you.

It ends up that The number of directories need to be the same as how you reference it with the bundles along with names being different.

> **Example**
>   using this structure
>   [image: directory structure]
>    bundle.cs
>
> ```
>   bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/one/two").Include("~/Content/Css/site.css");
> ```
>
> Layout.cshtml
>
> ```
>  @Styles.Render("~/one/two")
> ```