# IIS 7 won't serve kendo UI icons on production

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I googled this until my eyes bled.  I can't find what's causing it to save my life.

I'm using MVC4 with KendoUI HTML5 Framework; one of the 2015 editions.  Everything's .min so I can't find the exact version.

- On development, Kendo UI icons show fine.
- On a VM I created to test deployments, Kendo UI icons show fine.
- On the customer's network in production, Kendo UI icons do not show.
- On the customer's network, you can navigate to the location of the icon sprite file successfully (no 404 error)
- Bootstrap icons show normally in all cases.  It's only the Kendo UI icons.

Dev means there's no inherent problem with the icons or CSS.  The VM deployment working fine means it is most likely not an MVC bundling problem--I'm using the following solution for the bundling issue.

```
.Include("~/Content/kendo/kendo.bootstrap.min.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
```

I have absolutely no idea what is different on my customer's network that causes  KendoUI icons not to display. I'm baffled, and--as always--unbelievably grateful for any help you all can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, you can disable bundling on production, to see if it is related to the problem.

On the other hand, with bundling enabled, there should be some 404 error in the browser console when the sprite file doesn't load - I suggest checkng what the request URL is in that case, and compare it with the working URL when you access the sprite file directly.

Also check this thread that may be applicable:

[CssRewriteUrlTransform with or without virtual directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765238/cssrewriteurltransform-with-or-without-virtual-directory)

Comment: I know it's been forever, but I figured I should come back and thank you.  It was a virtual directory problem.  I don't remember the exact resolution, but I remember that thread pointed me in the right direction.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In my case the icons were not copied over to production. I copied the kendo sub folder from contents folder to the corresponding folder in production and that solved it. Visual Studio 2010 MVC 3. No bundling used.