# font-awesome not works in mvc5

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, font-awesome

I am using MVC5 .NET and I am trying in Release mode to show my fa icons.
I was trying to recompile base css bundle and nothing.

`.Include("~/Content/css/libs/awesome/font-awesome.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform());`

I can confirm, in debug mode it works, and in Release mode, it doesn't.

I ordered my bundles like this:

```
 var bundleCSS = new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css")
            .Include("~/Content/css/libs/revolution/settings.css")
            .Include("~/Content/css/libs/bootstrap/bootstrap.css")
            //.Include("~/Content/css/libs/awesome/font-awesome.css")
            .Include("~/Content/css/libs/ionicons/ionicons.css")
            .Include("~/Content/css/libs/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css")
            .Include("~/Content/css/libs/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css")
            .Include("~/Content/css/libs/magnific-popup/main.css")
            .Include("~/Content/css/libs/flexslider/flexslider.css")
            .Include("~/Content/css/libs/camera/camera.css")
            .Include("~/Content/css/custom/general.css")
            .Include("~/Content/css/custom/header.css")
            .Include("~/Content/css/custom/rooms.css")
            .Include("~/Content/css/custom/home.css")
            .Include("~/Content/css/custom/reset-styles.css")
            .Include("~/Content/css/custom/pages.css")
            .Include("~/Content/css/custom/sidebar.css")
            .Include("~/Content/css/custom/event.css")
            .Include("~/Content/css/custom/footer.css")
            .Include("~/Content/css/custom/responsive.css")
            .Include("~/Content/css/custom/Site.css")
            .Include("~/Content/css/libs/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css")
            .Include("~/Content/css/style.css")
            //.Include("~/Content/css/custom/header.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform());
            .Include("~/Content/css/libs/awesome/font-awesome.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform());


        bundleCSS.Orderer = new AsIsBundleOrderer();
        bundles.Add(bundleCSS);
```

Maybe ordering and CssRewrite does not functionate with each other?

Comment: Open font-awesome.css file and check url routes.

Answer (score 0):

On Visual Studio in the Solution Explorer go to where the font_awsome CSS file is located.

If the file icon is transparent right click "Include in Project", that would solve your problem.

Comment: Why do you have your font-awesome.css commented in your bundle?

Comment: because, I put down in CssRewriteUrlTransform()

Comment: I think that  CssRewriteUrlTransform() is your problem, check this anwser if it helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765238/cssrewriteurltransform-with-or-without-virtual-directory

Comment: didn't help. I will start over from scratch.